# My passing String is displaying in the URL of asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am storing some data in the string on the webform1.aspx page and then displaying it to another webform (named as backend.aspx) using query-string method. But my passing string is also displaying in the url of my application. 
This is code of my source page

```
 Response.Redirect("backend.aspx?name=" + connType + "");
 //conntype is my string
```

here i am retrieving on the destination page using that code

```
  string    ff = Request.QueryString["name"].ToString();
```

i have also set `cookieless = false` in webconfig file.

Here is snapshot of my problem[image]

Comment: You're performing a GET request and passing the value through the URL. You want to do a POST and pass the values through to your back end via a FORM.

Comment: Try to use sessions

Answer (score 0):

Query String always show the data in url. Use session or cookie for store and retrieve data.

Use Alternative option of passing Data

In the source page i.e. WebForm1.aspx, save the information that you want to pass in session state, as shown in the following example:

```
Session["Name"] = "StackOverFlow"; // Change with your original data
```

In the target page i.e. backend.aspx, read the saved information from session state, as shown in the following example:

```
string name= (string)(Session["Name"]);
```

Thank You.